# Select the row with maximum value for a column MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table name 'employee' and I need to get the row with the maximum value for Salary and  where the employee is from 'New York'.

```
select * from employee where city = 'New York' and MAX(salary);
```

Seems not working, Please suggest me a way

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this::

```
select 
* 
from employee 
where city = 'New York' 
order by Salary desc limit 1
```

Answer (score 2):

It is simple method. you can also use group by then sub query

```
select * from employee where city = 'New York' order by Salary desc limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this, you will get all the employees from New York that has the highest salary. I.E. if you have another employee with `salary = 2000`, you will get it too.

```
SELECT * FROM employee WHERE city = 'New York' AND salary = MAX(salary);
```